# Deploying the React/Nodejs/Mysql project from locally to AWS using AWS-Lamda RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, aws-lambda

I am struggling to configure back end using Lamda function, currently i have full stack application and locally it is working fine.
I have also managed to deploy the mysql server(aws rds) and front end page(S3 bucket) and when i try to deploy the backend (Lamda function) i got a bit confused with it.

Really appreciate if anyone can advise or give any pointer here for my below questions please.

**Q1-** I have dig around and can see that i can use export.handler but here i am having `two` API calls, do i need to make two saperate function and if so then do i need to upload two zip files with all the other dependencies in both the files

**Q2-**  is it the correct way to connect from Lamda function to rds DB as below , am i still able to do the same connect.query commads.... to use mysql(it is currently working fine if i access aws-rds from locally)

```
     let connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "root.cjfdyreioui1.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com", // here i connect to rds aws
          user: "root",
          password: "abc1234",
       
          database: "join_us",
          insecureAuth: true,
        });
```

-Snippet of `Backend-code` `server.js` that i zipped around 30mb (do i need to keep index.js filename instead)

```
    const express = require("express");
    const mysql = require("mysql");
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    const auth = require("./verifyTokenExisting");
    const authNew = require("./verifyTokenNew");
     const cors = require("cors");
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    const pdf = require("html-pdf");
    const pdfTemplate = require("./documents/pdfTemplate");
    const fs = require("fs");
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    
    app.use(
      cors({
        credentials: true, // for cookies
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
      })
    );
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "root.cjfdyreioui1.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com", // here i connect to rds aws
      user: "root",
      password: "abc1234",
   
      database: "join_us",
      insecureAuth: true,
    });
    
    
    
    //!  when clicked on signin page to verify after signin/
    
    app.post("/api/verifyifloginalready", (req, res) => {
      let token = req.cookies.yogaoutlet_access_token;
      //
    
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).end();
      }
    
      let decodepayload;
    
      try {
        decodepayload = jwt.verify(token, "lllfasdgfdadsfasdfdasfcadsf");
    
      } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
       
          // if invalid token
          res.status(401).end();
        } else {
          res.status(400).end();
        }
      }
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE email=?;", [decodepayload.email], function (err, results) {
        res.json(results);
      });
    });
    
    ////!  LOGIN & LOGOUT
    
    app.post("/api/newuser", (req, res) => {
      let x1 = req.body;
      
      if (req.body.logout === false) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE email=?;", [x1.email], function (err, results) {
        
          if (err) console.log("13333", err);
          else {
            if (results[0].email && results[0].password) {
         
    
              if ((results[0].password == x1.password && results[0].userloginStatus == true) || (results[0].password == x1.password && results[0].userloginStatus == null)) {
                const payload = { email: results[0].email };
                 const token = jwt.sign(payload, "lllfasdgfdadsfasdfdasfcadsf");
                 res.cookie("yogaoutlet_access_token", token, {
                  maxAge: 25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                  httpOnly: true, // it will enable on frotend-javascript to not have access to cokkies
                  
                });
    
                res.status(200).end();
    
                  connection.query(
                  "UPDATE  users SET userloginStatus=? WHERE email=?",
                   
                  ["1", results[0].email],
                  function (err, results) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(results);
                  }
                );
              } else {
                res.json({
                  data: "invalid  password",
                });
              }
            } else res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/about");
          }
        });
      } else {
        
        const payload = { email: req.body.email };
        console.log("339x", payload);
        const token = jwt.sign(payload, "lllfasdgfdadsfasdfdasfcadsf");
    
        res.clearCookie("yogaoutlet_access_token");
    
        res
          .json({
            data: "User Logged out",
          })
          .end();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1:
Yes, you use export.handler because Lambda needs an entry point. See the AWS Lambda developer guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

But Lambda can't run a server so your server.js file has to be adapted. You need something else to handle connections from clients. Perhaps API Gateway fits the bill.

When deploying you upload a ZIP archive: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html

Q2:
AWS Lambda running a Node function which uses RDS is not really my forte. But if your server connects, executes transactions and then disconnects quickly, it shouldn't be a problem. In any case, AWS CloudWatch will help you if you experience problems.